# java null pointer exception in test suite

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, selenium-webdriver

I am stuck at a situation.
Here i have created one testsuite with two test cases in it.
First test case is executed properly. In second test case, it throws error of `java.lang.NullPointerException` at `Webdriver driver`

**Test Case:**

```
 public class second{
    private WebDriver driver;

    @Test
    public void sample() throws Exception
    {
           System.out.println("tab bar");
           driver.findElement(By.id("tabs"));
           //My code
        }
}
```

Comment: Are you injecting the instance of `WebDriver` ?

Comment: Could you please post the complete class

Answer (score 1):

```
WebDriver driver;
```

is not initiated. What do you expect? The exception is absolutly correct.
You can try the following code to avoid the exception:

```
driver= new WebDriver();
driver.findElement(By.id("tabs"));
```

Comment: WebDriver is an interface and cannot be initialized, you should use the implementation like: 
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

Comment: ok. I just wanne show him the basics. I dont know this interface.

Comment: Thanks for the reply...i had already initialized in one class

Answer (score 1):

```
 private WebDriver driver; // initialize this
```

Comment: Thank for reply. But in every test case driver= new WebDriver(); is suppose to be initialized ? Am new to this so please consider

Comment: You may have to initialize in every class if you are going it with this way

Comment: In my first class also i have initialized "driver = new ChromeDriver"

Comment: Yes, that's why your first test case was success. You have to initialize driver here as well.

Comment: Else you may have to change your architecture using spring and use dependency injection

Comment: When i initialize in second test case, it opens another browser window of chrome

Comment: That's a matter since you are testing

Answer (score 0):

WebDriver is an interface and cannot be initialized, you should use the implementation like: `WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();`

Comment: Yes i agree,but i initialized it in my "First Class", so do i need to do the same in "Second Class" ? Here "Second Class" is continued to the "First Class". E.g: In my  "First Class" i did login and my "Second Class" contains script for further part. So what should i do in this case. I am new to this, so please advice.